# Laravel передача данных из посредника в контроллер (IoC)

Tags: php, laravel, inversion-of-control

Появилась нужда из посредника (middleware) при НЕ прохождении проверки редиректить с определёнными параметрами в контроллер. 
Никогда с IoC ещё не сталкивался и решил его использовать:

middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    $nowUserIp = $request->ip();

    $findIps = UserIp::where('ip', $nowUserIp)->get();

    if ($findIps->isEmpty()) {
        $newUserIp = new UserIp();
        $newUserIp->ip = $nowUserIp;
        auth()->user()->UserIp()->save($newUserIp);
    }

    foreach ($findIps as $findIp) {
        $hoursDiff = Carbon::now()->diffInHours($findIp->created_at, true);
        if ($findIp->user_id != auth()->user()->id && $hoursDiff < 24) {
            return redirect()->route('ip-ban');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

controller (куда в случае пойдёт /redirect. Сейчас с повторением кода, IoC не получается. Нужно передать из middleware `$findIps = UserIp::where...`):

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

    $nowUserIp = $request->ip();

    $findIps = UserIp::where('ip', $nowUserIp)->get();

    foreach ($findIps as $findIp) {
        $hoursDiff = Carbon::now()->diffInHours($findIp->created_at, true);

        if ($findIp->user_id != auth()->user()->id && $hoursDiff < 24) {
            return 'Access Denied! Your ip is banned: ' . $findIp->ip;
        }
    }

     return redirect('/');
}
```

Ничего не происходит, что я делаю не так?
Пробовал способ из этого вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212390/laravel-middleware-return-variable-to-controller/33297725#33297725 (Ответ **crishoj**) Ничего не выходит...

Comment: Не понятно по какому принципу вы создали этот код, почитайте https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware про то как это делается.

Comment: В ссылке что вы дали нет ни одного примера как передать параметры из посредника в контроллер или внедрение зависимости... Обновил пост

Comment: Читайте документацию Laravel, передать объект в контроллер можно по примеру в https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-model-binding, всё что потребуется это привязать путь к методу контроллера.

Comment: Есть наглядный пример как это сделать с посредником? Я бы не задавал вопрос, если бы это чисто и ясно освещалось в документации

Comment: Данные можно поместить в request через setAttribute метод, и извлекать getAttribute. Я к примеру этим пользуюсь чтобы проставлять глобальный идентификатор запроса и использовать эго на протяжении рабочего цикла приложения.

Comment: Можно примеры? Иначе когда я делаю переадресацию, весь запрос теряется

Comment: Хм, теперь я понимаю что у меня это в контексте одного запроса, а у вас новый запрос создаётся при переадресации. Вам скорее всего нужно сохранять нужные данные в память, либо подождать когда кто-то ещё, более знающий, сможет вам посоветовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Варианты:

### 1) Сохранить данные в сессию

RedirectResponse

Если передавать данные для роута который в url, то там нельзя передавать сложные данные, например, экземпляр модели или коллекцию.

К счастью, вместе с редиректом можно передать данные в сессию [Flash Data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#flash-data)(данные хранятся только для следующего запроса):

```
return redirect()->route('ip-ban')->with(['data' => $data] );
```

Получить можно так:

```
session('data');
```

Конечно, это работает для всех видов редиректов (через экземпляр RedirectResponse ), это тоже будет работать:

```
return redirect()->action(
    'TestController@testAction', 
    ['data' => 123] // данные роута
)->with(['data' => $users]); // данные в сессию
```

[Документация.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data)

### 2) Вызвать действие контроллера самому

В Middleware можно вызвать action нужного контроллера передав ему нужные данные.

Код тестировался с передачей коллекции Eloquent, значит скорее всего можно передавать что угодно.

Работал следующий код:

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::middleware('redirect')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/test', 'TestController@testAction');
});

Route::get('/test2', 'TestController@testAction2');
```

**Middleware "redirect"** (упустил код добавления в Kernel.php, не знаете как добавлять - [смотрите документацию](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware#registering-middleware))

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $users = \App\User::all();
    $controller = app()->make(\App\Http\Controllers\TestController::class);

    // передается массив параметров, `$users` попадет в первый параметр `$param`
    $controller->callAction('testAction2', [$users]);
}
```

Контроллер **TestController**:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function testAction()
    {
        return 'этот action не должен сработать';
    }

    public function testAction2($param)
    {

        // вывелась коллекция пользователей
        dd($param);
    }
}
```

На самом работает и без контейнера зависимостей, можно просто:

```
$con = new \App\Http\Controllers\TestController;
$con->callAction('testAction2', [$users]);
```

---

Пишите какие еще способы знаете.

Comment: Из middleware хочу передать выборку записей из DB в controller. Сейчас решил свою проблему, тем что и в mw и contr почти один и тот же код (дублируется)... Работает, но не очень хорошее решение

Comment: @Алексей я бы подсказал как не повторяться в двух местах, но не имею полного вашего кода

Comment: Если есть смысл весь код выкладывать - я могу выложить, но хотелось бы простого примера как передать из посредника данные (простая выборка записей из БД) в контроллер (при редиректе)

Comment: @Алексей дайте весь код посредника и желательного action контроллера который отвечает за маршрут `/ip-ban`

Comment: Я протестил рабочий вариант, щас обновлю ответ.

Comment: Проблема первого способа, в том что из посредника приходит ответ с $guard = null; и laravel ругается, не знаю хорошая ли это практика самому добавлять заголовки (чтобы из посредника приходило всё как надо) или делать исключение в VerifyCsrfToken. Попробуйте return $param; и поймёте о чём я

Comment: Не понял что за $guard. Используйте сессию тогда это даже еще лучше вариант если у Вас не API.

Comment: C сессией всё работает как надо! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

В документации и в исходниках `instance` примаент первый параметр как строку: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php#L391

Попробуйте этот вариант:

```
// свзязывает экземпляр с контейнером
app()->instance('userIp', $findIp);
```

Дальше в контейнере просто получите этот экземпляр. Вместо того чтобы писать

```
$this->findIp = app()->make('userIp');
```

Можно

```
$this->findIp = resolve('userIp');
```

Почему там в ответе используется "route model binding" если маршрут тут не причем я не знаю, по идее оно не должно работать.

Comment: Спасибо большое за первый внятный ответ! Но всё равно не выходит передать экземпляр (коллекции) нужной мне модели из посредника (middleware) в контроллер.

Comment: Instance в посреднике создаётся как надо, а вот контроллер его уже не видит "Class does not exist"

Comment: @Алексей, ааа, у вас там редирект... тогда могу предложить передать данные из middleware для `/ip-ban` и там делать UserIp::class. Можно даже еще проще, если у вас используется только ip, то можно ничего не передавать и этот ip получать в `/ip-ban`.  Ту тне удобно код писать, написал в новом ответе как это сделать.